# DocuSign .NET Client

Tags: docusignapi

We're new to DocuSign and have discovered that there are two different C# wrappers for their REST API; GitHub DocuSign C# Client and NuGet DocuSign.Integration.Client.dll. Is one 'more supported' by DocuSign then the other? Is there a preference to one over the other and if so why?

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 3):

DocuSign offers open source API clients that are auto-generated using Swagger.  As of this writing Java, C#, Objective-C, PHP, and Node.js are currently supported, but I believe more are on the way.

But yes moving forward DocuSign encourages, recommends, and supports the Swagger-generated API clients and not the previous versions which are deprecated.

Here are the Swagger generated DocuSign Clients:

- https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client
- https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client
- https://github.com/docusign/docusign-objc-client